# Fill matrix from list

Tags: r, matrix

I need to fill a matrix by coloumn.

I have this list:

```
> print(list_all)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 10

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 10


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 12

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 11


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 0

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 0
```

I want create a matrix like that:

```
N   perS    perM
10   12       0     
10   11       0
```

This is what I've done:

```
mat <- matrix(list_all[],
              byrow = FALSE,                         
              ncol = 3,     
              nrow = permutations*length(listN)) 
colnames(mat) <- list ("N", "perS", "perM")
print(mat)
```

and the result is:

```
     N      perS         perM
[1,] List,4 List,4      List,4      
[2,] List,4 List,4      List,4
```

How can I solve?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `unlist()` it first.  You can also set the names at the same time with `dimnames`.

```
## example list
x <- list(list(10, 10), list(12, 11), list(0, 0))

matrix(
    unlist(x), 
    unique(lengths(x)), 
    dimnames = list(NULL, c("N", "perS", "perM"))
)
#       N perS perM
# [1,] 10   12    0
# [2,] 10   11    0
```

You could also do it with `sapply()`, but the above method would be faster.

```
`colnames<-`(sapply(x, unlist), c("N", "perS", "perM"))
#       N perS perM
# [1,] 10   12    0
# [2,] 10   11    0
```

Comment: This is the solution I was going for and about to post. :) However, it does need you to specify dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a wrapper function `simplify2array`

```
`colnames<-`(simplify2array(x),  c("N", "perS", "perM"))
#     N  perS perM
#[1,] 10 12   0   
#[2,] 10 11   0
```